Hibernate Infinispan second level cache StackOverflowError
Is there a way to prevent the error in case of hierarchical (single table inheritance) entity model with lots of circular dependency e.g
class A extends BaseClass {

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aReferenceId")
    private BaseClass aReference;

.....
}

Repeating log entries until StackOverflowError comes.
 at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.CacheEntryHelper.assemble(CacheEntryHelper.java:75)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.StandardCacheEntryImpl.assemble(StandardCacheEntryImpl.java:132)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CacheEntityLoaderHelper.convertCacheEntryToEntity(CacheEntityLoaderHelper.java:449)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CacheEntityLoaderHelper.processCachedEntry(CacheEntityLoaderHelper.java:317)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CacheEntityLoaderHelper.loadFromSecondLevelCache(CacheEntityLoaderHelper.java:258)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrCached(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:345)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadWithProxyFactory(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:322)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadWithBytecodeProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:261)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:238)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:110)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:69)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:138)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1229)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1075)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:705)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.assemble(ManyToOneType.java:219)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.CacheEntryHelper.assemble(CacheEntryHelper.java:75)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.StandardCacheEntryImpl.assemble(StandardCacheEntryImpl.java:132)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CacheEntityLoaderHelper.convertCacheEntryToEntity(CacheEntityLoaderHelper.java:449)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CacheEntityLoaderHelper.processCachedEntry(CacheEntityLoaderHelper.java:317)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CacheEntityLoaderHelper.loadFromSecondLevelCache(CacheEntityLoaderHelper.java:258)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrCached(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:345)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadWithProxyFactory(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:322)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadWithBytecodeProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:261)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:238)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:110)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:69)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:138)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1229)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1075)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:705)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.assemble(ManyToOneType.java:219)
    at deployment.streamline_j2ee_app_claim.ear//org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.CacheEntryHelper.assemble(CacheEntryHelper.java:75)

